# Setting up Sanity Studio with Next.js 13 front-end gives me a SyntaxError

Tags: next.js, sanity, next.js13

I'm trying to set up Sanity Studio with my Next.js 13 front-end. I added `http://localhost:3000` to my Sanity project CORS origin and then, I created this `sanity.config.ts` file:

```
import { defineConfig } from "sanity";
import { deskTool } from "sanity/desk";

const config = defineConfig({
    projectId: 'p7dk6747',
    dataset: 'production',
    title: 'Por La Línea Studio',
    apiVersion: "2023-03-04",
    basePath: "/admin",
    plugins: [deskTool()]
})

export default config;
```

And this `app/admin/[[...index]]/page.tsx` file:

```
"use client";

import config from "@/sanity.config";
import { NextStudio } from "next-sanity/studio";

export default function AdminPage() {
    return <NextStudio config={config} />;
}
```

That should be it, but when I try to access `http://localhost:3000/admin`, it doesn't load and my console prints this error:

```
error - SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

How can I fix this?

I expected to be shown my project's Sanity Studio dashboard thought the following link: `http://localhost:3000/admin`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this is was turning the `AdminPage` from `app/admin/[[...index]]/page.tsx` into an arrow function and then exporting it in a separate line of code, like so:

```
"use client";

import config from "@/sanity.config";
import { NextStudio } from "next-sanity/studio";

const AdminPage = () => {
    return <NextStudio config={config} />;
}

export default AdminPage;
```

It appears to be a Next.js 13 bug, @Yaser and @Nimish pointed it out in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcTPaUfay5I&t=2428s).